# Multiple Serial Port listening in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, listener

There are loads of questions about listening of devices on Serial Port using C#.

However I couldn't find something about my problem.

Connected two serial port device one transmitter and one receiver.

1. When i start one application exe and check two port for listen async, after a
   while the reading stops for one of the com ports.
2. There is no problem when I start separate application for each port.

[ScreenShoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTdnw.png)

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Get a list of serial port names.
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            foreach (var item in ports)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
           
        }


        private void btnListenPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            doWork(checkedListBox1);
        }

        private async Task doWork(CheckedListBox cbl)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var itemChecked in cbl.CheckedItems)
                {
                    string sPort = itemChecked.ToString();
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        ListenAsync(sPort);
                    });
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void ListenAsync(string strPort) {

            var serialPort = new SerialPort(strPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_serialPort_DataReceived);
            serialPort.Open();

        }



        

        private void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort spL = (SerialPort)sender;
            string incomSting = spL.ReadLine();
            setText(spL.PortName + " " + incomSting);
        }

        delegate void serialCalback(string val);

        private void setText(string val)
        {
            if (this.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                serialCalback scb = new serialCalback(setText);
                this.Invoke(scb, new object[] { val });
                
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                richTextBox1.Text += val + Environment.NewLine;
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }
'''
```

Comment: Serial ports have two different modes 1) Continuous read 2) Master/Slave where you have to send data before a new message is received.  Which one(s) are you using?

Comment: try to set serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 0; before you open that port.

Comment: cannot set to 0 => Positive number required. (Parameter 'ReceivedBytesThreshold') @Ihdina

Comment: where can i check mode?  and i think that is not related with the mode because when i run two different application exe for each port everything is ok @jdweng

Comment: You can connect manually with Putty and emulate what is happening in your c# code.  With putty you in continuous mode should always show data in view without typing anything on keyboard.

Comment: Mode is just behavior of device.  If app is working with only one connection then you probably are not sending data properly.

Comment: replace with spL.ReadLine() with spL.ReadExisting()

Answer (score 0):

If you use `spL.ReadLine()` to read data, you must add a new line ("\n") at the end of your data.

```
ex:  spL.Write("your transmitte data \n");
```

Solution: Try to replace with `spL.ReadLine()` with `spL.ReadExisting()`